# What does “Awaiting Reviewer Scores” mean within the context of a prosemanager submission system?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, journal-workflow

I submitted a paper to Journal of Intelligent and Fuzzy Systems that uses the prosemanager submission system. The manuscript status has changed from "Awaiting Reviewer Assign" to "Awaiting Reviews(8 outstanding)".

And now "Awaiting Reviews(8 outstanding)" changes continuously to "Awaiting Reviews(7 outstanding)", "Awaiting Reviews(6 outstanding)", ..., "Awaiting Reviews(4 outstanding)" with time.

What does this change mean? What is the flow chart of the different statuses for a manuscript for this "Awaiting Reviews"?

Comment: I imagine it was waiting for 8 reviewers to respond, then 7, then 6, then...